# maximum step of sorting network

Tags: sorting, network-flow

How to calculate the maximum step of sorting network?

Based on image below, it has most comparators at second index which is 9 comparators than another indices. That's mean, overall networks need 9 forward propagation steps which is the 9 is the maximum step of sorting network.

This network has 6 elements input. How about `n-elements` input, how do I know maximum steps of sorting network based `on n-elements` or `n-wires`.

Also, is most steps always in the second index of networks?

source image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#/media/File:Six-wire-pyramid-sorting-network.svg

[image: sorting network]

Comment: (I've seen this called the *depth* of a (sorting) network.)